# Object doesn't support this property or method (Error 438) - ActiveCell.Offset?

Tags: excel, vba

I have error 438 message but cannot figure out why ? Do you have an idea ?
For each cells in my range B5:B28, I want to check string value and print a number accordingly to that string to the cell next to the right.

```
Public Sub RolloutStage()

    Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In Worksheets("backEnd_Lost&Found").Range("B5:B28")

        If Worksheets("backEnd_Lost&Found").rng.Value = "Live" Then
        Worksheets("backEnd_Lost&Found").ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 8
        
        ElseIf Worksheets("backEnd_Lost&Found").rng.Value = "Configuration" Then
        Worksheets("backEnd_Lost&Found").ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 7
        
        ElseIf Worksheets("backEnd_Lost&Found").rng.Value = "Testing" Then
        Worksheets("backEnd_Lost&Found").ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 6
        
        ElseIf Worksheets("backEnd_Lost&Found").rng.Value = "Planned" Then
        Worksheets("backEnd_Lost&Found").ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 5
        
        ElseIf Worksheets("backEnd_Lost&Found").rng.Value = "Pending" Then
        Worksheets("backEnd_Lost&Found").ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 4
        
        ElseIf Worksheets("backEnd_Lost&Found").rng.Value = "Not planned" Then
        Worksheets("backEnd_Lost&Found").ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 3
        
        ElseIf Worksheets("backEnd_Lost&Found").rng.Value = "No contact" Then
        Worksheets("backEnd_Lost&Found").ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 2
        
        Else
        
        Worksheets("backEnd_Lost&Found").rng.Value = "Not interested"
        Worksheets("backEnd_Lost&Found").ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 1
        
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: It's just `rng` not `Worksheets("backEnd_Lost&Found").rng`

Comment: `ActiveCell` make sense only if the sheet containing it is active. It is  not a property of the `Worksheet` object. You should simple use `ActiveSheet`.  That's why the error. In your case you must use `rng` also, as suggested above for solving the other coding mistake...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct version. Thank you

```
Public Sub RolloutStage()
    
        Dim rng As Range
        For Each rng In Worksheets("backEnd_Lost&Found").Range("B5:B28")
    
            If rng.Value = "Live" Then
            rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = 8
            
            ElseIf rng.Value = "Configuration" Then
            rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = 7
            
            ElseIf rng.Value = "Testing" Then
            rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = 6
            
            ElseIf rng.Value = "Planned" Then
            rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = 5
            
            ElseIf rng.Value = "Pending" Then
            rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = 4
            
            ElseIf rng.Value = "Not planned" Then
            rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = 3
            
            ElseIf rng.Value = "No contact" Then
            rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = 2
            
            Else
            
            rng.Value = "Not interested"
            rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = 1
            
            End If
        Next
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

### Conditionally Populate Adjacent Cells

**In your code...**

- You cannot use a variable as an object's property: instead of `ws.rng.Value`, use `rng.Value`.
- A worksheet has no `ActiveCell` property: instead of `ws.ActiveCell`, use `rng`.

**The For Each...Next Loop**

- What does the `For Each cell In rg.Cells` line do? You could think of it that in the first iteration, it writes the following invisible line right below:

  ```
  Set cell = rg.Cells(1) ' B5
  ```

  So in the continuation, you will use **this cell** to check the value and again use
  **this cell** to write another value to the cell adjacent to the right.
- In the next iteration, the invisible line looks like this:

  ```
  Set cell = rg.Cells(2) ' B6
  ```

  etc.

**An Improvement**

```vb
Public Sub RolloutStage()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("backEnd_Lost&Found")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range("B5:B28")

    Dim sCell As Range, dCell As Range
    
    For Each sCell In srg.Cells
        Set dCell = sCell.Offset(, 1)
        Select Case CStr(sCell.Value)
            Case "Live": dCell.Value = 8
            Case "Configuration": dCell.Value = 7
            Case "Testing": dCell.Value = 6
            Case "Planned": dCell.Value = 5
            Case "Pending": dCell.Value = 4
            Case "Not planned": dCell.Value = 3
            Case "No contact": dCell.Value = 2
            Case Else: sCell.Value = "Not interested": dCell.Value = 1
        End Select
    Next sCell
 
End Sub
```